# Should I rollback a user's own edit?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The OP of [this rock identification question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/18039/revisions) vandalized his own question in a fit of pique.

I flagged the question for deletion, but then I thought maybe just rolling back the edit might be a better idea. Then it would go back to a perfectly normal, garden-variety (inadequate) rock identification question.

**Update**: I just found [this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214673/to-rollback-or-not-to-rollback) about the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, please rollback edits that vandalize a user's own post. This is a little more important when the post is relevant/on-topic, but the same rule should generally apply everywhere. By rolling back the edit, we prevent nasty non-Q&A content from being on the site, while either keeping good-quality content or (in the case of poor-quality content) preserving the post so the user or someone else could possibly improve it.